# Cypher - find nodes whose related nodes have properties contained in a set

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I need a cypher query to search for something like this:

I have a graph (a)-[r]->(b) and (a)-[r]->(c) were a is a person and b and c are 2 different skill nodes.
Let's suppose I am looking for someone knowing both java and fortran.
Say b has property name:“java” and c has property name:“fortran”.
How do I find a person that has ALL specified skill nodes?

It'd be useful if the query was scalable, i.e. if I had 20 skill nodes, it would be also easy to execute it.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to `MATCH` your `Person` nodes to `Skill` nodes, filter `Skill` nodes for your properties and count the number of nodes per `Person`. If it's as large as the array of properties your filtering, the `Person` has all the `Skills`

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[r:HAS]->(s:Skill)
WHERE s.name IN ['java', 'fortran', 'cypher']
RETURN DISTINCT p, count(s)
```

I think you can combine this with a `CASE` statement to return the data:

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[r:HAS]->(s:Skill)
WHERE s.name IN ['java', 'fortran', 'cypher']
RETURN
CASE
WHEN count(s) = 3
THEN p
ELSE 0
END
```